# Why can't I install uTorrent Server on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, 32-bit, utorrent

I've seen a detailed tutorial on installing u-torrent but after i enter,  last line of code, it says:

```
'bash: /usr/bin/utserver: No such file or directory'

syntax; utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

Comment: I think it is best to use `transmission` if you intended  to download only. However here - http://askubuntu.com/q/104094/35775 is a brief tutorial. I think you missed the step while creating hard link `sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver`

Comment: give us the Tutorial link and terminal code in paste bin . Thank you .

Comment: Web-E; Thank you for your response.I tried those steps again and at the line which you said that i missed it..It said 'ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/utserver': File exists'. And after entering the final syntax it ended up showing the same error which i posted above. Hope you understood what i said,thank you

Comment: His problem is he downloaded the 32-bit version but doesn't have `ia32-libs` (see answer)

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer to this question, if you feel it solved your problem or helped you out (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as \"answered\" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 10):

#### You must install 32-bit compatibility libraries or use the native 64-bit uTorrent Server

- You are using 64-bit Ubuntu
- You downloaded the 32-bit version of `utserver`, which requires the `ia32-libs` compatibility package on 64-bit Ubuntu (or you get the cryptic *file not found* error)

  - You can fix this problem with `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
- **Better yet**, get the native 64-bit version of uTorrent Server:

  - `wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-ubuntu-10.10-27079.x64.tar.gz`
  - After that you will need to install *libssl v0.9.8* to get it work, with `sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8`

---

#### Educational screenshot, or "how did you know that?":

[image]