# Install uTorrent

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, utorrent

I followed these 2 tuts:

[Step by step installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step)

[Stuff if you are with x64 OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160814/why-cant-i-install-utorrent-server-on-ubuntu)

Well, I am done until the pre-last step. I have created the symlink, and when I navigate to the folder `.../opt/utorrent-server-v3_0` I can see the `utserver` file. But when I run the command `utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/` 
[image]

Therefore I cannot open the `localhost:8080/gui/`... Any ideas what might be the problem and how to proceed?

Comment: Is utorrent nessesary for you this is very simmeler sudo apt-get install qbittorrent

Comment: why not just use transmission?

Comment: Can you sudo nautilus /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/ && nautilus /usr/bin/ And confirm that both locations have a utserver bin file and then right click them and check the permissions are set as executable, if not change them

Comment: [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) is similar in interface to Utorrent(Minus the ads!). `sudo apt-get install deluge`

Answer (score 0):

`utserver` is not in your PATH yet. Run with:

```
./utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

or

```
/opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

Then see [How do I add an executable to my search path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322772/how-do-i-add-an-executable-to-my-search-path)

Comment: Or just add it to the alternatives system...

Comment: What does this have to do with the user interface. One way or another, the system just has to find the server executable, and I think adding software to the alternatives system is a better approach than adding its installation directory to the path.

Comment: What you're talking about are MIME type application associations. This is something else than the alternatives system. The alternatives system actually just symlinks the selected program to `/usr/bin/` (Well, this could also be done manually...)

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure how to do that with `update-alternatives` (if that's what you're talking about?).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to adding the installation path to `$PATH`, you could also create an entry for µTorrent in the Alternatives System:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install usr/bin/utserver utorrent-server /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver 100
```

This will create a symlink to `/opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver` in `usr/bin`. The differences to adding it to $path are:

1. Works in environments where custom PATH is not set
2. User indepentent (Well, setting the PATH for all users is possible too...)
3. Finding the binary is managed by the system, and not by the user

   - This may not be important for µTorrent, but it could help if you have multiple versions of a program installed, e.g. one compiled yourself and one from the packages, or multiple Java versions.

The general `update-alternatives` installation syntax is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install <link/to/be/created> <name> <link to the binary> <priority, the higher, the more preferred>
```

To change the defaut for any alternative, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config <name>
```