# Same program, different version, in different locations...how to specify which to use?

Tags: bash, paths

Hi all I'm trying to run a program called cufflinks on my machine, however there appears to be a version of this in multiple places on my existing system.   For example when I typed `whereis cufflinks` I get a few directories.  I have downloaded the executables (cufflinks comes with other related programs) and so-far I've been just doing something like `/myownbing/cufflinks` - and it works until it tries to call other cufflink programs and it says my version is not updated because it tries to run the default.

is there anyway I can tell my system to use only my veresion?  eg `/myownbing/cufflinks` instead?  I don't have admin rights because it prohibits me to type in sudo anything.

thanks in advance. 
Ahdee

Comment: the_Steppi posted an excellent answer about this a little while ago: http://askubuntu.com/a/515986/158442

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set the correct executable search path when invoking your program:

```sh
export PATH="/myownbing:$PATH"
cufflinks
```

Or shorter but without altering the environment of the executing shell:

```sh
PATH="/myownbing:$PATH" cufflinks
```