# How to change port number utorrent in ubuntu?

Tags: installation, localhost, utorrent

I just [installing Utorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step) in ubuntu but I want to change the port number localhost:8080 to localhost:8085 because my apache geronimo server using that port number. can i change the port number? thanks.

Comment: Is there any config files in your $HOME ? Like a .utorrent folder ?

Comment: no there. there was only Docs folder

Answer (score 5):

A super easy way to change the port through the simple webUI and the port change persists even after reboots and even in automatic startup :

1. Open the utorrent webUI.
2. Then go to **Settings** and select **webUI** option

[image: Settings]

3. You will fing a text-box with 8080(or the current port). Change the port to whichever you desire.

[image]

4. Click on **Save Seetings.**

[image]

5. Close the WubUI, wait a few minutes and its done!

This worked for me for v3.3

Answer (score 2):

Edit  `utserver.conf` file located under uTorrent installation directory. If you don't find it go ahead and create one.

Add the following line to `utserver.conf` file

```
ut_webui_port: 8085
```

Check this [link](http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/utorrent/utserver.conf) for more available settings that can be used with uTorrent `utserver.conf` file

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not as simple as that. Modifying utserver.conf in the installation directory does not necessarily change the port on a restart of the program.

Comment: Can you tell me the path where to create or find the utserver.conf file?

Comment: I found the directory here */opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3*. Created the file utserver.conf. I saved and restarted the pc but it still opens the port 8080! Help!

Comment: I had the same problem. Removing the *.dat files solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the old extracted file and create new one
- Now before starting the utserver create a `utserver.conf` file in the same directory and put `ut_webui_port: desired_server_port`into the file, or as a one-liner:

  ```
  echo "ut_webui_port: desired_server_port" >  utserver.conf
  ```
- Save the file and
- Now start the utserver, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

About the "utserver.conf" file, please consider :

> This file is configuration setting for uTorrent for Linux. If you're
>   making changes to an existing config file, be sure to delete or rename
>   the settings  files. They'll be recreated upon startup.
>
> Many of these settings are only read from the configuration file when
>   the uTorrent settings file settings.dat does not already exist in the
>   settings directory. Once settings.dat exists, the values specified in
>   the configuration file for these settings will be ignored, and the
>   values stored in settings.dat will be used. For other settings, the
>   server will load the values from the configuration file every time the
>   program starts or receives a request to reload the configuration file.

In other words : utserver.conf must be created BEFORE the first launch of utserver, OR you must delete settings.dat to force utserver.conf to be applied.

Most important, when launching utserver, you must use argument "-configfile".
Example :

```
 # utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ -configfile /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver.conf -daemon
```

Hope this will help :)

Sources:
https://gist.github.com/drunkirishcoder/d48ddde9f55ea64b1183

Answer (score 0):

In case your utorrent GUI webinterface does not work any more after doing this (happened to me when I changed port from 8080 to 8085), here is what I did to revert to original 8080 port in unix command:

1. Make sure the utserver process is killed

   ```
   pkill utserver
   ```
2. In you utorrent directory (for me `/opt/utorrent` replace this with your utorrent directory in all following descriptions) remove all the `.dat` files by typing

   ```
   rm *.dat
   ```

   These `.dat` files will be automatically recreated at relaunch of utserver
3. Create a `utserver.conf` file containing the port to use by typing

   ```
   echo "ut_webui_port: 8080" >  utserver.conf
   ```
4. Launch the command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to interupt if nothing happens after 2 min.)

   ```
   ./utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent/ -configfile /opt/utorrent/utserver.conf
   ```
5. launch utserver

   ```
   utserver
   ```
6. You should be able to access again webui using "admin" and a blank as logins

   ```
   ipdevotreserver:8080/gui/web/index.html
   ```
7. Configure your new logins in webui by clicking WebUI tab and input your new login and password and clicking save
8. Click the directories tab and tick the "move completed download to" and input a directory ex. `/opt/utorrent/`

You are done it should work again ;)