# How do I install utorrent after I encounter the problems in the description?

Tags: 12.10, bittorrent, utorrent

How do I install `utorrent`? I have [downloaded the tarball from here](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/complete/os/linux), extracted it to `/home/brentonhorne/utorrent-server-v3_0` and run:

```
cd /home/brentonhorne/utorrent-server-v3_0
./utserver
```

Which takes me to:

```
brentonhorne@brentonhorne-Vostro-3500:~$ cd '/home/brentonhorne/utorrent-server-v3_0' 
brentonhorne@brentonhorne-Vostro-3500:~/utorrent-server-v3_0$ ./utserver
server started - using locale en_AU.UTF-8
Using locale en_AU.UTF-8
File not found during integrity check: /home/brentonhorne/utorrent-server-v3_0/settings.dat
File not found during integrity check: /home/brentonhorne/utorrent-server-v3_0/settings.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: /home/brentonhorne/utorrent-server-v3_0/settings.dat.old
File not found during integrity check: .//settings.dat
File not found during integrity check: .//settings.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: .//settings.dat.old
total physical memory -1 max disk cache 33554432
File not found during integrity check: .//dht.dat
File not found during integrity check: .//dht.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: .//dht.dat.old
File not found during integrity check: .//rss.dat
File not found during integrity check: .//rss.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: .//rss.dat.old
File not found during integrity check: .//resume.dat
IPv6 is installed
File not found during integrity check: .//resume.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: .//resume.dat.old
```

At which point I get stuck and it stays at this step way for days. I am running 12.10.

After I ran

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

I received the output:

```
server started - using locale en_AU.UTF-8
Using locale en_AU.UTF-8
total physical memory -1 max disk cache 33554432
Loaded ipfilter.dat (0 entries)
IPv6 is installed
```

At which point it froze just as it did with the commands listed earlier.

Comment: I know this doesn't related to your problem in no way, but try Deluge Torrent client! It's very similar to Utorrent and easy to run.

Comment: I use Vuze and it gets the job done. I've used deluge and I wasn't too impressed, I prefer its relative QBittorrent but Vuze is great too. I want to have utorrent at my disposal, however. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find this useful [How to install utorrent step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step) . But from my experience, [Deluge](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/deluge/) is very good alternative to uTorrent, maybe even better.

[Edit] I found out that you can simply ignore these warnings, go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/` in your browser and put ***admin*** as username and left the password blank.

Comment: I've seen that page and it didn't help me because it leads me to the same/similar errors as I received and documented above.

Comment: What I find is, that probably you can ignore these and just try to run Web GUI http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=104672

Comment: That worked! Now if you write in your answer to open up http://localhost:8080/gui/ in your web browser and type "admin" for username and leave the password field blank I will accept your answer and give you the bounty.

Comment: Sorry I gotta wait 23 hrs to reward this bounty... I will when I can