# What is a "failed to create a symbolic link: file exists" error?

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a symlink in my home directory to a directories and files on my data partition. I've tried:

```
~/Documents$ ln -sv ~/Documents/saga /media/mariajulia/485f3e29-355c-4be3-b80a-1f5abd5604b6/mariajulia/Downloads/saga..doc
```

to create a symlink named `saga` in my `Documents` directory in my `home` folder. The terminal output is:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/media/mariajulia/485f3e29-355c-4be3-b80a-1f5abd5604b6/mariajulia/Downloads/saga..doc’: File exists
```

I was checking the content of `~/Documents` with ls -a , there is nothing but `.` and `..`. In general my `home` folder is empty, it's just a fresh system installation.

Comment: Thanks. It seems my question is not very useful. Should I delete it? Or you convert your comment in the reply so I could accept it as solved :)

Comment: Your question has a score of four, so apparently the community decided that it _is_ useful. Also, even if you tried you wouldn't be able to delete the question, since it has an answer with a score of 1 or more.

Comment: I got my answer to this question from here (on this forum): http://askubuntu.com/questions/379647/failed-to-create-symbolic-link-usr-bin-utserver-file-exists/379649#379649

Comment: Use `ln -sf` instead of `ln -s`. Be careful though, as this may overwrite your original file with a broken symlink. Check what's been typed carefully *before* you add the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is a classical error... it's the other way around:

```
ln -s Existing-file New-name
```

so in your case

```
ln -sv /media/mariajulia/485f3e29-355c-4be3-b80a-1f5abd5604b6/mariajulia/Downloads/saga..doc ~/Documents/saga
```

should work. Note though:

1. if `~/Documents/saga` exists and is not a directory, you will have the error too;
2. if `~/Documents/saga` exists and is a directory, the symbolic link will be `~/Documents/saga/saga..doc` (are you sure about the double dot?)
3. if `~/Documents/saga` does not exists, you symbolic link will be `~/Documents/saga` (as it is, no extension).

Comment: Always remember that the parameter order is as in `cp`

Comment: ... as discussed [here](http://superuser.com/q/522287/354511) on Super User.

Comment: My mnemonic for this is "what where", e.g., link what where, move what where...

Comment: There's even `cp -s`.

Comment: what if that New-name already exists?

Comment: But what if my file doesn't exist... yet?

Answer (score 49):

I have same error message
when redirecting

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

from node.js v0.10.25
to node.js v4.2.3
so I look at `man ln`
and use

```
[OPTION] 
-f, --force
          remove existing destination files
```

This is work as I expected.

Comment: i dont actually get your answer/point, what is the whole script you used? I think we have the same problem

Comment: I think what he is suggesting to to add --force to your ln command ln -sv ~/Documents/saga /media/mariajulia/485f3e29-355c-4be3-b80a-1f5abd5604b6/mariajulia/Downloads/saga..doc --force

Comment: So that'd be `ln -sf` ...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 22):

As @Rmano responded in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/543528/75166) the arguments were in the wrong order. I made the same mistake pretty often too. Thus I found a

### Fool-proof way to create symbolic links

First go into the directory where you want to create the link

```
cd ~/Documents/saga
```

Then create the link with a **single argument**.

```
ln -s /very/long/path/to/target/Downloads/saga..doc
```

This will create a link to the current directory with the same name as the target.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add new information, you can remove the current symlink, then re-create the symlink.

```
rm  ~/Documents/saga
```

Then re-create the symlink:

```
ln -sv /media/mariajulia/485f3e29-355c-4be3-b80a-1f5abd5604b6/mariajulia/Downloads/saga..doc ~/Documents/saga
```

Hope this helps anyone who still faces 'file exists' error.

Answer (score 2):

Might be unrelated.
For me the link was dead. Pointing to a non existing folder. When trying to replace it, it would fail with this message. ^
So a simple `rm linkName` was enough.