# "/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory" on terminal startup

Tags: 20.04, nodejs, npm

I just updated to 20.04 and every time I open a terminal `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory` shows at the very top. I have searched for answers but in the questions I found, npm did not work. It works for me though. I have no clue where to look or what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you used NVM for your node and npm, this may help:

```
nodepath=$(which node); sudo ln -s $nodepath /usr/bin/node
```

NVM installs it somewhere out of the norm, so creating this link solved my issue.
You can run the command `which node` in your terminal to see where NVM installed it if you're curious.

Comment: When I get `failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists`. 
Node is in `/home/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/node`. I don't know if that says anything.

Comment: That's fine. Mine is: `/home/william/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node` Did you try running that command?

Comment: Ok, I made it work, but I am not sure why. I removed my node version and installed the LTS instead and then I overwrote using the flag -f (thanks to [Alexander Glulkhovtsev](https://askubuntu.com/a/732692/991495)

Comment: From nvm maintainer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734737/470749