# My terminal crashes with this error "ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists"

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python, symbolic-link

I'm not sure why it's happening.
tried to add more symbolic links or change it but it is not happening, it's giving another error that there are too many symbolic links.

some more issues I'm running into when I'm trying to do a build from my git repo are:

`WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`

```
E: Unable to locate package vim
E: Unable to locate package dh-autoreconf
E: Unable to locate package git
E: Unable to locate package make
E: Unable to locate package libexpat1-dev
```

while doing *apt-get update* :

`E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'`

I have tried editing the /etc/apt/apt.conf , /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99cnf-update-db files and using this command `sudo apt-get install command-not-found`
did not work. I think it's all due to the error in my heading. please help me out.

Comment: It is unclear what you did.

Comment: I tried following this https://askubuntu.com/a/543528 to fix the issue but didn't work.