# How to install utorrent.tar.gz on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-installation

I know to install software from terminal using some `sudo apt-get` stuffs but I can't install utorrent by terminal. So, I download .tar.gz from their website. So please instruct me how to install .tar.gz or say the way to install it from terminal friends.

Comment: Have you read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step

Comment: Ubuntu comes with a bit torrent client preinstalled. try out *Transmission*

Comment: Deluge, is my default torrent application. It's interface is similar to Utorrent. Minus the ads ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install [utorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent) from the Ubuntu repos as this programme doesn't work natively on Linux. You can use it via Wine, though.

You can follow the [uTorrent under Ubuntu in 3 Easy Steps](http://news.softpedia.com/news/uTorrent-under-Ubuntu-in-3-Easy-Steps-49037.shtml) tutorial:

> Step 1 - Install Wine
>
> Step 2 - Download and Execute [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/)
>
> Step 3 - Create a desktop shortcut for the uTorrent application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to open Ubuntu Software Center. Search for 'qBittorrent', and install. I found it far better than utorrent (miu-torrent). All the best.