# How to associate .torrent files with utorrent server?

Tags: file-association, utorrent

I just installed µTorrent Server for Ubuntu 12.04 (3.3 build 30470) using this step by step guide [How to install utorrent step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step) and it works just fine.

Now I want to start a torrent just by double-clicking the .torrent file.

To do this I need to create an association with utserver. The problem is that utserver doesn't have a .desktop file that I can edit in order to make the association.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It seems that my question is much more difficult than anticipated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My little <del>pony</del>hack

1. Create directory for torrents:

   ```
   mkdir ~/torrents
   ```
2. Add this as autoload directory:

   [image]
3. Create script `torrent-utserver.sh` and place it in `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # little helper script
   mv "$@" ~/torrents
   ```

   Change permissions to execute

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/torrent-utserver.sh
   ```
4. Associate `*.torrent` files to this script

   [image]

Voila! It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you just can't. The µtorrent server is just... a server. There's no client/user interface outside the WebUI. You would need to move the torrents to a directory to add them automatically to the queue, otherwise I doubt you can do anything useful.

If you don't want that I recommend you using other clients.

Comment: But OP can associate torrent files with script which will add them into appropriate directory. This is kinda like a hack, but it will work as desired.

Comment: @Danatela yeah, but I wouldn't use it if there's already something more easy/lazy, that I could do. Setting a directory and telling utorrent to add all torrents from there seems like The Right Thing To Do™

Comment: @Danatela Can you please expand/elaborate your comment? I would try your version of doing things but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @AugustinJ OK, I will write it in answer.