# How to install uTorrent v3.3 on 14.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, utorrent

I've attempted to install utorrent on 14.04 using the Terminal and attempting to install libssl 0.9.8, but with no success. Also, this utorrent version is V3.3 and is located in my Downloads. I've already attempted the post which mine was a dupe of ([How to install uTorrent step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step) )

Comment: Hi could you provide more details on how you are trying to install, any error messages you get.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

#### Install uTorrent Server 3.3

#### Step 1: Download latest uTorrent Server from [here](https://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux)

**Note**: (You need to download uTorrent Server for 13.04, also works for Ubuntu 14.04)

#### Step 2: Extract uTorrent Files

- Launch terminal (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or search <kbd>Terminal</kbd> in dash and click to open it)

  Change directory to Downloads folder

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/
  ```
- Extract uTorrent files to the /opt directory

  ```
  sudo tar -xvzf utserver.tar.gz -C /opt/
  ```

#### Step 3: Set Permission

- Set permission on uTorrent-server folder

  ```
  sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
  ```

#### Step 4: Set Symbolic link

- Run the command to link uTorrent server to the /user/bin directory.

  ```
  sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
  ```

#### Step 5: Start uTorrent

- Run the following command in the <kbd>Terminal</kbd>

  ```
  utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
  ```

**Note**: If you get an error about `libssl.so` package missing, then

- Run the command below to install it:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
  ```

  then try starting it again.

#### Step 6: Log into uTorrent

- Open Firefox/Chrome and browse to the URL

  ```
  localhost:8080/gui
  ```
- The username is admin and leave the password field empty

[image]

Original post from [www.sysads.co.uk](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-utorrent-3-3-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/)

**Note2** : If `libssl0.9.8:i386` isn't working, try `libssl0.9.8`, 
if that also doesn't work, you probably need `libssl1.0.0` (Ubuntu 16.04) .

Comment: At first, everything succeeded apart from the in-browser client where admin and blank pass would just show up a blank page, but then I reset my PC, and it worked that time. Many thanks.

Comment: Where does it store its files by default?

Comment: It stores the files in the Home folder by default. There is also an direct download option.

Comment: Getting error on step 5 saying:bash: /usr/bin/utserver: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: Change `chmod 777` to `chmod 755`. It's never a good idea to give other users write permissions, especially on executable files

Comment: @abhishah901 Which version of turrent did you download? Maybe you have downloaded 64bit version while your Ubuntu is 32bit. 32 bit systems cannot run 64 bit binaries or you are trying to run x86 version on an ARM CPU. **@Serg** updated

Comment: The link in Step 1 appears to be broken.  Any ideas what it should be?

Comment: @fossfreedom Direct link to the download file also will be broken?

Comment: If you faced the same problem @Sharky talked about >> a white screen after starting the server and opening the web page, then so a rest is meaning that restart your laptop and start the server again.

Comment: I'm getting error messages in some of the steps: xxx@xxx:~/Downloads$ sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/utserver': File exists
xxx@xxx:~/Downloads$ utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3
bash: /usr/bin/utserver: No such file or directory

Comment: @KasiyA how do you change the port?

Comment: I get a javascript error saying that `token.html` doesn't exist.

Comment: I get error "utserver command not found" any idea why?

Comment: Now, I'm running 17.04 so maybe it just isn't going to work and that's just too bad, but I get nothing on step 5. <code>ps ax | grep utorrent</code> shows the process running, but all I get in konsole is a newline.

Comment: In 17.04, you have to copy the utserver file from /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver to user/bin using nautilus before you perform step 4. Also use the following command to set the symbollic link instead of the one given in the answer:-                                                                                                  
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver. Note:I am not sure if this is the right way to resolve the errors but it worked for me

Comment: how to run this at startup? can you just place the utserver command in the etc/rc.local file?

Comment: This procedure worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04. But I have to repeat these step over and over. Is there any way to run it by one click, like any app or something?