# Utorrent 13.04 for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: utorrent

Im new to ubuntu, and im trying to install utorrent.

Ive installed the library with the command

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

because

```
sudo apt-get -y install libssl0.9.8
```

didn't work.

Now i have to extract some files right, i use `sudo cp ~/Downloads/utorrent-server.tar.gz.ubuntu-10.10-27079.tar.gz /opt/`, it says no such file or directory. I've also downloaded the utorrent server.

Can you please help me with the instructions.

Thank you.

After Rinzwind did a edit on my post, I tried again with the latest command:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/utorrent-server.tar.gz.ubuntu-10.10-27079.tar.gz/opt/
```

it says:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/home/home/Downloads/utorrent-server.tar.gz.ubuntu-10.10-27079.tar.gz/opt/’
```

Comment: You should try out rTorrent. It works great with 14.04. Just do `sudo apt-get instal rtorrent`. I can validate it works with 14.04.

Comment: I will try this also, but i want to become a bit familiar with ubuntu commands, will let you know if it works.

Comment: You will need to wait for a 14.04 version of utorrent. Looks likt the older utorrent versions seem to use a openssl/32-bit component that has been removed.

Comment: So if im correct it will work with ubuntu older versions?

Comment: Did you try this http://askubuntu.com/a/530961/215526

Comment: Yes i got this: tar (child): utserver.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Did you download the file in the link? If so please post the output of `ls ~/Downloads`

Comment: hello_world.php  utserver.tar.gz
php5

Comment: You're trying to copy a nonexistent file. Instead do `sudo cp ~/Downloads/utserver.tar.gz /opt`. If I didn't put the correct file name of the .tar.gz just change it with what you have, which can be checked by a simple `ls` in your downloads directory

Comment: It says: command not found. I installed rtorrent. Now to figure out how to work with this pogram.

Comment: http://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/tutorial-using-rtorrent-on-linux-like-a-pro/ under usage has good info