# How to install utorrent step by step for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: utorrent

am trying to install utorrent instead of using the torrent apps and I just came off windows seven can someone help me?

Comment: Please use our search first before asking questions. This should cover all your questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at Transmission. It comes pre-installed and is simple and lightweight.