# How to uninstall utorrent 3.3 in ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS?

Tags: software-uninstall, utorrent

I followed the steps from here: [How to install uTorrent v3.3 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04/530961#530961?newreg=72331296c4234f7b895f7abe6bf34cec) to install utorrent 3.3.

Now I would like to uninstall it.

How can I do that?

Comment: There should be an uninstall option in whatever installer you used; but I'm not seeing utorrent in apt-get, in which way did you install it originally?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04/530961#530961?newreg=72331296c4234f7b895f7abe6bf34cec this was the used method for installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### One easy step:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3 /usr/bin/utserver
```

This command deletes both the installation directory and the link to the program's executable.

Comment: it says: 
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/bin/utserver’: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the output of this command? 'which utserver' (Without the single quotes)

Comment: i don't get the question. could you please elaborate?

Comment: Open a terminal and type the following one `which utserver` and press Enter. What is the output?

Comment: Hello, i opened the terminal and typed `which utserver` and nothing happened.

Comment: If you've kept exactly to the instructions in the intallation (https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04/530961#530961?newreg=72331296c4234f7b895f7abe6bf34cec), then everything is fine now.