# Remove uTorrent from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, utorrent

I followed the steps found here [How to uninstall utorrent 3.3 in ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598151/how-to-uninstall-utorrent-3-3-in-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts) but when I access the localhost server, uTorrent is still there. Did I miss anything?

Comment: It is, in fact, very possible, but we have no way to know, unless you provide more info. :~)

Comment: What info do you need? I basically just installed ubuntu, downloaded that utorrent .tar.gz file, extracted it using http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/09/setup-%CE%BCtorrent-server-ubuntu-16-04/ this tutorial, and then removed it using the provided answer. (I hope links are permitted).

Comment: For example, what do you mean by "uTorrent is still there"? How do you know? Can you also try the removal command with -v option, and add the output to the question: `sudo rm -rv /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely you did not stop uTorrent process - **utserver**.
It will be running until stopped even if you deleted all uTorrent files.
Restart and it should be gone.