# How to download torrents using utorrent on your browser (firefox)

Tags: command-line, firefox, utorrent

There is method for downloading torrents without opening actual program using browser. 
I just go to open firefox type in `https://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/`
After it I go to terminal and paste a command related utorrent. Anyone familiar with this procedure. It kind of downloading torrents file remotely.

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is here:  http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/19/control-utorrent-from-a-website/

Comment: Although, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: thx for ur help but thats not the answer firstable i said without installing the actual program plus it has something to do with ubuntu cuz there is some command line that u have to type it in the terminal to use this

Comment: It really has to do with a third party app, utorrent, but here is another site that could help with the installation and configuration.  I just set one up as well.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04

Comment: thx alot this it i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Aria2 and the Web GUI instead of utorrent because utorrent are not trustworthy especially considering they tried to sneak in cryptomining with your computer, meaning they waste your resources and your power to make themselves money. - http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-quietly-installs-riskware-bitcoin-miner-users-report-150306/

Instead use Aria2 which is a command line downloader and then use Web GUI to accomplish what you are wanting.

Aria2 - http://aria2.sourceforge.net/

Web GUI - https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2