# Issue when attempting to install utorent 3.3

Tags: tar, utorrent

After attempting to set a symbolic link this comes up (I assume this mean I have done it already, which would make sense because this is one of many attempts).

```
:~/Downloads$ sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/utserver’: File exists
```

When attempt to start utorrent, nothing happens. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong I have followed the steps of a guide previously posted on this site. I would really appreciate it, Thanks!

Comment: Might find your answer here.  Might need to try reinstalling it from scratch.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04

Comment: I've tried that in the past and tried it again just now. Still won't work :( , I definitely appreciate the comment though.

Comment: I'll just run utorrent in wine until I figure this out.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is there a particular reason you chose uTorrent on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed this on my system.  I recommend removing the link before you follow through the instructions here.  To remove the link from a terminal type in:

`sudo rm /usr/bin/utserver`

then follow through on this link.

[How to install uTorrent v3.3 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04)

I do recommend on the last line of:

`utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/`

to change that line to:

`utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ &`

so it runs in the background.  Also, you can add it to your start up applications, and put that exact same line as above ending in the `&` so it can run at start up.

When you open your Firefox or whatever browser you want to use, type in:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui`

to access the utorrent application.