# cannot access files downloaded from Wine application for Utorrent in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, utorrent

i downloaded Utorrent for windows 
I downloaded Wine application in my Ubuntu OS.
I ran utorrent using Wine application.
It worked well.
But then, after i had downloaded the files.

When i click on "open Folder", it opened a folder with downloaded files. But i am not able to open any of them.
I also cannot able to copy, move the files from that folder where it was downloaded.

{ Since the utorrent has default Save location as C:\user\downloads..
it has assumed it that way., now i m not able to retrieve it back]

Please HELP!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just curious, is it a specific reason you're using p2p via Wine? There are lots of p2p clients you can use directly from Ubuntu one of them installed is Transmission, you can use Deluge, qBittorrent which have a look like uT.

Comment: You could setup Utorrent so it works in Ubuntu without using WINE but by using a browser.  Here is the info I followed and it works:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04

Answer (score 0):

So I guess your problem is that you can't find the downloaded files from your non-Wine environment.

By default wine creates a hidden folder in your `/home` called `.wine`. This is called your `WINEPREFIX`. Naturally (as with everything in linux) this location can be changed, but I'll assume that you left it at the default.

So you have your `WINEPREFIX` in the `/home/<user>/.wine` folder. If you look into it you will see a `drive_c` folder which is exactly that, your "`C:`". In that folder you will have an exact copy of a Windows filesystem.

So your file's paths will be something along the lines of `/home/<user>/.wine/users/<user>/dowloads/`.