# Installing utorrent on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, utorrent

I've followed all instructions outlined in this link:

[askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04cd Downloads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04cd%20Downloads)

but come upon an error like this:

```
user@host:~/Downloads$ sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/utserver’: File exists
user@host:~/Downloads$ utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
No command 'utserver' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ttserver' from package 'tokyotyrant' (universe)
 Command 'ktserver' from package 'kyototycoon' (universe)
utserver: command not found
```

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Zviad** suggested, DON'T USE UTORRENT!

Not only is uTorrent is in tight association with MPAA, it's full of ads, it's a botnet that records your IP and whatever you download.

use:

- [Deluge](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/deluge/)
- [qBittorrent](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/qbittorrent/)

I'm not saying your problem is not fixable, but it's not worth it...