# Need assistance in installing μtorrent on Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, utorrent

Need assistance in installing μtorrent on Ubuntu OS 14.04. Not sure where to extract the files. File have been downloaded, need help with extracting the files.

Comment: http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install uTorrent v3.3 on 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

There's no μTorrent version for Ubuntu 14.04; you may try to install the version for Ubuntu 13.04:

1. Download the appropriate μTorrent Server for Ubuntu 13.04 version for your architecture (32-bit / 64-bit) from [utorrent.com](http://www.utorrent.com/intl/en/downloads/linux);
2. A good place to install additional software is `/opt`; assuming that you downloaded the tarball in `~/Downloads`, decompress / extract it in `/opt`: in a terminal, run `sudo tar zxf ~/Downloads/utserver.tar.gz -C /opt`;
3. Set the permissions of `/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3` to `0777` recursively, so that all the extractes files / folders are readable / writable / executable from everyone: in a terminal, run `chmod -R 0777 /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3`
4. Place a symbolic link to `/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utorrent/utserver` in `/usr/bin`: in a terminal, run`sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utorrent/utserver /usr/bin/utserver`;

To run it, just run `utserver` in a terminal; you may also want to add an entry to the Unity Dash to start it straight from the GUI.

Comment: i am going to try that, one explanation what does tar zxf do exactly?

Comment: @AvinashMvrick tar is a command used to extract .tar / .tar.gz / .tgz (and so on) archives. About zxf, those are 3 tar BSD-style options "compressed" toghether; z=decompress, x=extract, f=output to a file rather than stdout

Comment: @AvinashMvrick Also after step 2, do the chmod step outlined in the linked duplicate: chmod -R 777 /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3, since those files should be readable / writable / executable from everyone

Comment: works for me, able to launch gui now.