# How to correct uTorrent installation instruction error?

Tags: xubuntu, utorrent

Downloaded the 64bit uTorrent package for Ubuntu (13.04) and followed the instructions here: [How to install uTorrent v3.3 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04), to install uTorrent on my 64bit laptop with Xubuntu 14.04 but cannot get past Step 5:

Step 5: Start uTorrent

```
Run the following command in the Terminal

utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
```

I get the following message:

ineuw@laptop:/opt$ utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3

No command 'utserver' found, did you mean:

Command 'ttserver' from package 'tokyotyrant' (universe)

Command 'ktserver' from package 'kyototycoon' (universe)

utserver: command not found

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

please avoid those steps.

1. Extract the utserver into a folder as you wish.
2. `cd` into corresponding folder using terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   ./utserver
   ```
3. Without closing the terminal go to the preferred browser and type: `http://localhost:8080/gui/web/index.html`
4. Type username admin and press Enter.