# How to install uTorrent 14 + Ubuntu

Tags: utorrent

I have run these commands to install `uTorrent` but I get an error. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

```
wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz -C /opt/
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/

utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This may be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/q/530955/57576

Comment: You are aware that Ubuntu comes with the Transmission BT client by default? Just to make sure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing `libssl0.9.8:i386` using below command:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```