# bssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, bash, utorrent

I followed this tutorial: [How to install uTorrent v3.3 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04)

On the Step 5 I get this error `bssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Utorrent Server alpha 3.3
How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Sure the error wasn't about `libssl...`. That lives in the `libssl1.0.0` package. The answer to the previous question mentions this albeit with a slightly different package number.

Comment: @Oli so, what can i do to fix it, i'm completely new to ubuntu and whole linux

Comment: @Oli I did something and now it prints : `utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: You did something?

Comment: yeah, I did for libssl1.0.0 same error ( I mean for libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ) and then I got this error alive...