# How to install utorrent in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 18.04, utorrent

I have tried the installation with basic running the file,

then with the instructions given by the post [command line - How to install utorrent v3.3 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04)

But after all of this, on running the following command

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
```

I found that the terminal is not even responding.

It's been 5 minutes waiting in that screen before taking the screen shot

[image]

By my search, there are no guides for installing utorrent in the Ubuntu 18.04.

- Please help me in the comments to clarify the question.

Comment: Clearly, it is not a duplicate, because any of the related answers did not work for me.

Comment: "Didn't work" in the way shown in your screenshot usually means a crash or a bug or a failure to follow install instructions. It does not mean a non-duplicate.

Comment: Why do You specifically want utorrent, maybe try other torrent client like `deluge` ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I tried installing many windows apps in ubuntu, it worked well.

Comment: So, I was wondering why couldn't I install the ubuntu version of utorrent in ubuntu, but I have been used to it. I've tried installing it many times but the answer was same.