# uTorrent server issue

Tags: utorrent

I installed the utorren server ( [instruction](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/linux-mint-how-tos/how-to-install-%CE%BCtorrent-utorrent-on-linux-mint-19-linux-mint-18.html) used)

After all I launched utserver and tried join with localhost:8080/gui but got the 404 error in the result.

[image]

**Please help me to solve this issue**

Comment: Assuming you've installed uTorrent on Ubuntu, I think it isn't the best option available, unless you want to work on porting uTorrent to Ubuntu. From what I've seen so far, it has never worked well on Linux, and is still in the alpha stage. Transmission daemon is a much better, reliable and tested program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install utorrent step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step) ( `sudo snap install utorrent` )

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks. This is a solving =)