# Confused using Deb-get

Tags: helpfile

Is using `deb-get` the fastest way to install a app, eg I wanna install uTorrent, so would I preinstall from GitHub `deb-get`?

Then afterwards would I download uTorrent official for Linux, then run `sudo apt install` then drag and drop the downloaded file from Firefox? Or would I need to add `sudo apt install latest` and then drag and drop?

Comment: Welcome. Your question is very confusing, and it seems you're mixing up different ways of doing things.

Comment: For packages in the Ubuntu repositories, the command `sudo apt install [package]` is the fastest there is. But you appear to be interested in packages outside the repositories which have their own installation instructions.

Comment: If you want utorrent I'd recommend to take a look at [qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/), very similar user interface, add free and available in official Ubuntu repositiories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install utorrent step by step?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step)

Answer (score 4):

This answer will try to clear up some confusions in your question, and thus might or might not directly answer your question.

1. `deb-get` is a 3rd party application to install selected software packages that are not in the Ubuntu repositories. The list is [available here](https://github.com/wimpysworld/deb-get/blob/main/01-main/README.md), and uTorrent is NOT on that list - so this can't be installed with `deb-get`.
2. While it seems uTorrent is still developed, clearly their website and Linux ports are not. The latest [official uTorrent version](https://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux/) for Ubuntu is for Ubuntu 13.04, which is absolutely ridiculous (pardon my french). This is a HUGE red flag for me, and I would consider other options.
3. If you were actually to install software using `deb-get`, you wouldn't need to do anything in the GUI - so everything about "drag and drop" and "Firefox" is completely out of the question here.
4. Finally, for installing software inside the repositories (or from files you've manually downloaded), you would need to run `sudo apt install <packagename>`. This is the completely standard way of doing it, but you don't do this if you install in another way (such as with `deb-get`).
5. As suggested by @mook765, a good alternative is qBitTorrent, which is available in the Universe repository. So after you've [enabled the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository), you can install this package with: `sudo apt install qbittorrent`

Hopefully this will help clear up some misunderstandings.